# Problema al agregar etiquetas div desde javascript

Tags: javascript

Bueno, he buscado y he mirado mi código intentando encontrar el error pero no me doy cuenta que es.

Les explico un poco, traigo pedidos de mi bd, utilizo la api de waypoints de Google Maps donde le paso un array con las direcciones de los pedidos para que me devuelva el orden según la mejor ruta, así los puedo mostrar en un listado en ese orden.

Este es mi js, donde armo los div con los datos del pedido

```
function armarListado(){
    var div = document.getElementById("listado");
    var i = 0;

    console.log("Orden: " + orden.length + ", Waypoints: " + waypoints.length);
    // Esto devuelve:
    // Orden: 3, Waypoints: 3

    while(i < waypoints.length){   
        var temp = "";

        temp += "<div id='"+waypoints[orden[i]].id+"' class='listaPedidos'>";
        temp += "<a href='DetallesServlet?id="+waypoints[orden[i]].id+"'>";
        temp += "<p>#"+waypoints[orden[i]].id+"</p>";
        temp += "<p>"+waypoints[orden[i]].desc+"</p>";
        temp += "<p>"+waypoints[orden[i]].dir+"</p>";
        temp += "</a></div>";

        div.innerHTML = temp;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Lo que pasa es que solo me muestra 1 div con la información, los otros 2 no aparecen y no me doy cuenta de por que puede ser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu variable `temp` siempre la declaras vacia una vez que entra al ciclo `while`, por ende siempre va a quedar el ultimo registro. Esto deberia quedar asi :

```
var temp = "";
while(i < waypoints.length){   
    temp += "<div id='"+waypoints[orden[i]].id+"' class='listaPedidos'>";
    temp += "<a href='DetallesServlet?id="+waypoints[orden[i]].id+"'>";
    temp += "<p>#"+waypoints[orden[i]].id+"</p>";
    temp += "<p>"+waypoints[orden[i]].desc+"</p>";
    temp += "<p>"+waypoints[orden[i]].dir+"</p>";
    temp += "</a></div>";

    div.innerHTML = temp;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que es que no estás concatenando el resultado:

```
var resultado = "";
while(i < waypoints.length){   
    var temp = "";

    temp += "<div id='"+waypoints[orden[i]].id+"' class='listaPedidos'>";
    temp += "<a href='DetallesServlet?id="+waypoints[orden[i]].id+"'>";
    temp += "<p>#"+waypoints[orden[i]].id+"</p>";
    temp += "<p>"+waypoints[orden[i]].desc+"</p>";
    temp += "<p>"+waypoints[orden[i]].dir+"</p>";
    temp += "</a></div>";

    resultado += temp;
    i++;
}
div.innerHTML = resultado;
```